# 4x4 keyboard matrix not generating unique keycodes

Tags: verilog, matrix, keypad

I have a 4x4 keybord matrix fsm scanner but it generates only high keycode setting all last 4 bits to 1 and second and fourth digits to high.
Is there anything wrong in my code here?

```
module keyboardScanner (input clk, input [3:0] col,output reg [3:0] row, output reg [7:0] keyCode);
reg [1:0]state=2'b00;
reg [1:0]nextState=2'b00;

//state register
always@(posedge clk) begin
    state <= nextState;
end

//output CL
always@(posedge clk) begin
    case (state)
    2'b00: row <= 4'b0001;
    2'b01: row <= 4'b0010;
    2'b10: row <= 4'b0100;
    2'b11: row <= 4'b1000;
    default: row <= 4'b0001;
  endcase
    if (col != 4'b0000) begin
    keyCode <= {row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3], col[0],col[1],col[2],col[3]};
    end
end

//next state CL
always @(posedge clk) begin
        case (state)
            2'b00: nextState <= 2'b01;
            2'b01: nextState <= 2'b10;
            2'b10: nextState <= 2'b11;
            2'b11: nextState <= 2'b00;
            default: nextState <= 2'b00;
        endcase
end

endmodule
```

Please help me. It used to work 2 days ago, but now... :/

Comment: Do you have any documentation or schematic for us?

Comment: Are you using the Digilent keypad as a Pmod device? There is the possibiliy of floating inputs ... you should enable pullups in the FPGA's IOBs.

Comment: I found the original Digilent example code for the 4×4 keypad. You have to drive `column` and read `row`! This prevents you from having floating inputs.

Comment: Ok, I have found a board picture, but I can't find any schematic. Have a look at the Digilent [PmodKYPD](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,401,940&Prod=PMODKYPD) and its [schematic](http://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/PMODKYPD/PmodKYPD_sch.pdf). As you can see the columns have no pullup or pulldown resistor, whereas the rows have. That means columns have to be driven and rows to read. Please compare it to your beti board schematic.

Comment: There is no resistor in either of them in beti board so its quite different. No matter if you choose row or col as driver it will be the same. Thanks for information, it will be helpful knowledge :)

Comment: Can I ask what FPGA's IOBs are? I have no idea

Comment: `IOB` stands for Input/Output Block. An FPGA is divided into different blocks, which are organized in a regular array stracture: Configurable Logic Blocks (CLBs) , Switch Matrices, Clock Modifying Blocks (CMBs like DCMs, PLLs, MMCMs, ...), Hard Macro Blocks (like Ethernet, PCIe, ADC blocks) and IOBs. A IOB contains the pad (the physical pin), the input and output amplifiers, the input and output register and if they are more advanced some delay circuits. Mostly, an IOB has switchable pullup and pulldown resistors.

Comment: So if neither the `column` nor the `row` lines have resistors, you need to add resistors, by enabling them in the IOB cell. Have a look at the linked PmodKYPD schematic: The series resistors prevent the pins of a short if 2 buttons in the same columns are pressed. The pullup resistors on the row lines prevent the input pins from floating. You should also note that the scan frequency has an upper bound: So as a rule of thumb, keep it below 10 kHz.

Comment: Great suggestions. I appreciate that. Thank you sir. That helped me a lot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It was a clock halt problem. Clock was grounded and it destroyed the thing. Now it works fine!