# col not declared issue{Verilog}

Tags: verilog, keyboard, matrix, keypad

I am having a problem here can't make this code compile. It is a 4x4 keypad scanner with a 20ms debouncer. It gives error "Error: 'col' has not been declared"
Any suggestion?

```
module keyboardScanner (input clk, input wait20, ,input [3:0] col,output reg [3:0] row, output reg [7:0] keyCode);
reg [1:0]state=2'b00;
reg [1:0]nextState=2'b00;
reg start = 0;
//state register
always@(posedge clk) begin
    state <= nextState;
end

//output CL
always@(posedge clk) begin
    if(start == 0)begin
        case (state)
            2'b00: row <= 4'b0001;
            2'b01: row <= 4'b0010;
            2'b10: row <= 4'b0100;
            2'b11: row <= 4'b1000;
            default: row <= 4'b0001;
        endcase
    end
    if (col != 4'b0000)
        start = 1;
    if ((col != 4'b0000) && (wait20 == 1) && (start == 0)) begin
        keyCode <= {row[1],row[2],row[3],row[0], col[0],col[1],col[2],col[3]};
        start = 0;
    end
end

//next state CL
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if(start == 0)begin
        case (state)
            2'b00: nextState <= 2'b01;
            2'b01: nextState <= 2'b10;
            2'b10: nextState <= 2'b11;
            2'b11: nextState <= 2'b00;
            default: nextState <= 2'b00;
        endcase
    end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: You have an extra comma (```,```) in your module declaration just before where the ```col``` input is declared. If you wrote it out neatly with each input/output on its own line rather than mushing everything up into one line, this would be obvious. Neat code = easy debug.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am really tired of designing FSMs and coding. Thanks a lot. It helped me! :D

Comment: Possible duplicate of [4x4 keyboard matrix not generating unique keycodes](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/199796/4x4-keyboard-matrix-not-generating-unique-keycodes)

Comment: As in your [last question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/199796/51354): what device/keypad do you use? My research shows that you must swap the pin directions of columns and rows.

Comment: @Paebbels I am using basys2 fpga. Why should I do that? It's the same thing.

Comment: @Paebbels I am using a 4x4 button matrix of beti board sold here in Turkey.

Comment: Ok, I have found a board picture, but I can't find any schematic. Have a look at the Digilent [PmodKYPD](http://www.digilentinc.com/Products/Detail.cfm?NavPath=2,401,940&Prod=PMODKYPD) and its [schematic](http://www.digilentinc.com/Data/Products/PMODKYPD/PmodKYPD_sch.pdf). As you can see the columns have no pullup or pulldown resistor, whereas the rows have. That means columns have to be driven and rows to read. Please compare it to your beti board schematic.